# why is props only working in render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code inside render and when I console log it, the correct values appear:

```
    render() {
        const { total } = this.state;      
        const filter = this.props.catalog.filter(word => word.markets.some(m => m === this.props.currentMarket))
        
        console.log(filter)
        console.log(this.state.filtered)
}
```

But when I do the same for a `componentDidMount()` hook it doesn't work.

```
export class Products extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
      this.state = {
        filtered: []
      };
    }


  componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.catalog.filter(word => word.markets.some(m => m === this.props.currentMarket)))

    const filter = this.props.catalog.filter(word => word.markets.some(m => m === this.props.currentMarket))
    this.setState({
      filtered: filter
    })
  }
  

  renderProductCards() {
    return <ProductCard product={this.props?.catalog}/>
  }

  render() {
    const { total } = this.state;      
    const filter = this.props.catalog.filter(word => word.markets.some(m => m === this.props.currentMarket))
    console.log(filter)
    console.log(this.state.filtered)
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="ui divider"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So for the first render hook I get the correct values of the filter but for `componentDidMount()` I get nothing as the value, I get the state value but it doesn't setState correctly and when I console log it it appears nothing.

Comment: Please post the code where the `<Products>` element is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

When updating state using previous state or props, the callback argument should be used.
See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

It should be

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState((state, props)=> ({
        filtered: props.catalog.filter((word)=>(
            word.markets.some(m => m == props.currentMarket)
        ))   
    }));
}
```

Comment: still same issue

Comment: Fixed an issue. Please check `props.catalog`  using `console.log` in the `setState`

Comment: props.catalog is an empty array but when I console.log catalog in render() it logs the props

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you didn't call `super(props)` in your `constructor`. Try this:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props); // Add this line to constructor
  this.state = {
     //states
  };
}
```

Comment: still same. The console log appears as nothing

Comment: Can you send the whole file?

Comment: Yes, I've edited with full code